# Create a box with CSS styling

Tags: html, css

**[image: strong text]**

I need to create a box as shown in the attached image with CSS styling. Is it possible to do with CSS or would I have to use the image.

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Comment: Here you go: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's as close as I could get in 10 minutes...

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nsK32/3/)

```
#bubble {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 180px; 
  background: #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
  position: absolute;
}
#bubble:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 36px solid transparent;
  border-left: 18px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 13px solid transparent;
  margin: 180px 0 -25px 240px;
  transform:rotate(10deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(10deg);
}
```

There's scope for improvement - the 'border' (actually a drop shadow) is only present on the main box, not the arrow, but it otherwise does a decent job on fidelity: the arrow shape and angle are all there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tool [here](http://cssarrowplease.com/) that makes this effect very simple. Highly customizable too. Once you can see how it is working it is easy to tweak for example moving the arrow further to the right rather than dead center.